# Android: Create listview with data from SQLite

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have interface like this image

[image]

So i create 2 file XML Place and Place1

Code Place.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/filter_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >
</EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Code Place1.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_landscapes" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_place"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@+id/label_place" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@+id/label_address" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_Phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@+id/label_Phone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is code in activity class:

```
public class Place extends Activity {

private String DB_NAME = "Danang Travel.sqlite";

String[] from;
int[] to;

ListView lvPlace;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterPlace;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.place);

    EditText filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filter_text);

    lvPlace = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lvPlace.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    // **********************************************************************
    SQLiteDatabase DB = null;
    Intent t = getIntent();
    Bundle extra = t.getExtras();
    String temp = extra.getString("k");
    try {
        DB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        Cursor c = DB.rawQuery(
                "SELECT Name,Address,Phone FROM ServiceDetail Where SerID = '"
                        + temp + "' ORDER BY Name", null);

        from = new String[]{"Name","Address","Phone"};
        to = new int[]{R.id.label_place,R.id.label_address,R.id.label_phone};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.place1, c, from, to);


        lvPlace.setAdapter(adapter);
```

It doesn't work! I really don't understand why? Please help me!

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Do you get empty ListView?

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah: It can't run this layout

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah: Error: android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:302)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:104)

Comment: would be great if you post the full logcat from the begining of the erros to the end so its easier to look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this working sample code with ListActivity class, very useful for beginner. Just study it properly and implement in your code,

Its simply read data from db and uses ArrayList class to store the values, and ArrayAdapter to set values in ListActivity.

```
public class CRUDonDB extends ListActivity {

    private final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "myFriendsDb";
    private final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "friends";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

        try {
            sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                    " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Makam','Sai Geetha','India',25);");
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Chittur','Raman','India',25);");
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Solutions','Collabera','India',20);");

            Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " where Age > 10 LIMIT 5", null);

            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                        int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                        results.add("" + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }

            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));

        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        } finally {
            if (sampleDB != null) 
                sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
                sampleDB.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to create interface for listview like this image http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg191/scaled.php?server=191&filename=capture1zd.png&res=landing

Comment: now, i  create two layout like above but it don't working, it have errors: android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:302) android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:104)